# Better than Jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, telerik-mvc, datatables

I need an advise, I am using Jqgrid as a grid tool, somehow I am finding some complication of showing very big data I am talking of 450 records with big data and 10 columns in there.

Is there any better grid you guys suggest to work with which gives me a better performance

Comment: I'm not sure what would be happened in telerik MVC grid, but as you completely work on client-side it is better to check their new product Kendo UI which is faster than their current MVC grid (as they told here : http://www.kendoui.com

Comment: They also about to introduce wrappers for MVC. If there are not that many columns 450 records could be handled - although its always better to enable virtual scrolling or paging.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used dataTables and i always reccomend it because it's easy to use and configure. It is perfect and fast to display data ( i used it with tables with more than 100.000 rows with no problems, configuring server side procesiing correctly ).
The only thing you must now is that (as far as i know) it doesn't support colspan in the body of the table so, if your layouts require that, using datatables becomes impossible. (i usually found other way to show things rather than using colspan but for some this is a blocker)

Comment: In fact, it's still doable to set `colspan` attribute of cells in `fnRowCallback`, something like:
`"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iFullIndex) {
        var colSize = $(nRow).find('td').length;
        $(nRow).find('td:gt(0)').remove();
        $(nRow).find('td:first').attr('colspan', colSize);
    }`
Though it's manual and not simple/elegant enough...